# Mac OS X Leopard Kernel Panics getting absurd

Tags: macos, troubleshooting, osx-leopard, kernel-panic

Today Mac OS X kernel panicked twice on me.
The first time, I got [this](http://pastie.org/637601) log.
The second time, I got [this](http://pastie.org/637602) log.

A few minutes ago, iTunes started sounding blocky, after quitting FireFox everything went back to normal, I am currently using Opera.

[These](http://pastie.org/637604) are my system's specs.

EDIT: I ran the apple hardware test and got these results.

Without extended testing:

[image: without extended testing]

With extended testing:

[image: with extended testing]

Comment: **It just works!**  Except when it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there could be quite a few things...

But, here's the top few that might help.

1) Download the Mac OS 10.5.8 Combo-Updater, and run that...
2) Check Virtual Box, and make sure that you have the latest version installed, along with the virtual box tools in your windows session / boot camp.

Let us know what happens....  And try checking your memory as suggested with the other answers...

---

Try reseting your RAM, and Hard drive.  Disconnect all USB & Firewire devices, and if possible try running Tech Tool Pro, in extended hardware tests...

Something is obviously causing a problem...  But there doesn't seem to be a obvious reason for it.

---

What antivirus packages do you have loaded? And do you have Virtual PC installed?  Is there any software packages that you have installed or updated recently?

Comment: I do not have any antivirus programs installed, so far I haven't gotten any kernel panics...

Answer (score 4):

Kernel Panics are nearly always a sign of a hardware issue, most likely one of your memory sticks has developed errors. You can try finding out for sure by either running the Extended Test on the Apple Hardware Test section of your Restore DVD (hold <kbd>D</kbd> when you start up and have this disc inserted).

Alternatively you can try using [memtest](http://www.memtestosx.org/joomla/index.php) to test your RAM to isolate what stick has gone bad. It's also quite plausible the logic board is having issues instead but your best bet if you can't find out yourself (with the two tests I mentioned) is to take it to your local Apple Authorized Service Provider and have them check it out.

Comment: Also, even better news, I live in the Dominican Republic, so unlike you guys in the states, it really isn't an option to get it repaired here (WAY too expensive)

Comment: If it is a RAM problem, sometimes re-seating the RAM will eliminate the problem.

Comment: @Henri W: Some of us don't live in the States either. ;-)

Comment: @Chealion: Canada doesn't count, they have Apple owned stores there. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar situations (same pmap_flush_tlbs error) with an '07 MacBook Pro (ATI X1600 graphics) from one of our deployed MBPs, and after about 3 or 4 days of wrestling with re-installations, diagnostics, etc, I decided to call Apple and get it replaced.

According to Apple tech, it could be a logic board problem. What you could do is try running diagnostics (hold down 'D' when booting up). However, I strongly recommend you to send it in to Apple - they'll get it replaced pronto.

Comment: Problem is, I have no warranty because this *is* a '07 MacBook Pro.

Comment: Talk to Apple nicely - explain to them that this is probably a logic board failure and you would like to seek assistance in getting it replaced.

Comment: Call them, explain the situation - you will be surprised at how far Apple can go in customer service.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off Time Machine, and see if the panics cease.

There are a number of known reports of Time Machine causing periodic Kernel panics on some Macs. My wife's MacBook Air had this issue, and a clean install got it running again, but it would eventually re-occur during backups. Becuase the panic doesn't occur on most backups, and the geniuses couldn't reproduce it, they advised her to disable time machine's auto-backups and run it manually every week or two.

Oddly, my machine backs up to the same time machine without incident, but hers continued to have it from time to time even after they replaced her entire motherboard and hard drive (for seemingly unrelated reasons).